# Selenium IDE - form fields filled but considered empty

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE for Chrome (and Firefox) to create tests on forms for user creation.

I am facing a problem with my test. Selenium works well to fill all fields but then, when it clicks on the Create button there is an alert because all required fields are not filled so test is in error and stop.
However, if I manually click on the button, my user is created and I don't know why there is a difference.

Here are a screenshot of the form and the part of my selenium test.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZLpN.png)
[Selenium test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn168.png)

I tried to use selenium ide with chrome and firefox and the result is the same.
I tried to change the focus with selenium before clicking on create but it's the same.

If anyone has an idea, I didn't find my solution in documentation and previous posts here.